# Providing minimum implementations for overloaded comparison operators in Swift

Tags: swift

I was pondering this morning how to properly implement the comparison operators in Swift. I have a class (a very lightweight date class) for which I have overloaded the equality operator:

```
func == (lhs: SimpleDate, rhs: SimpleDate) -> Bool {
    if (lhs.day != rhs.day) {
        return false
    }
    if (lhs.month != rhs.month) {
        return false
    }
    if (lhs.year != rhs.year) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

But I would now also like to be able to use `>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=`. When it comes to providing this functionality, is it a requirement to write all 4 functions?

It follows that for `>=` you could build on the already-written combination of `== || >`, but I was wondering if there was any way for this functionality to be automatically determined by Swift if it sees that `==` and `>` have both been implemented.

ie. is there a way to, *rather than write these 5 globally-scoped functions in my class*, override a special function/operator that allows me to return an `NSComparisonResult` or similar, and let Swift automatically overload all these operators for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is given in the ["Swift Standard Library Reference"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/):

> [**Equatable**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Equatable.html)
>
> The Equatable protocol makes it possible to determine whether two
>   values of the same type are considered to be equal.
>
> There is one required operator overload defined in the protocol: ==.
>
> [**Comparable**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Comparable.html)
>
> The Comparable protocol makes it possible to compare two
>   values of the same type.
>
> There is one required operator overload defined in the protocol (<),
>   as well as one defined in the inherited Equatable protocol (==). By
>   adopting the Comparable protocol and adding an operator overload for
>   <, you automatically gain the ability to use >, <=, and >=.

So it is sufficient that your class conforms to `Comparable`, and the `==`
and `<` operators are implemented:

```
class SimpleDate : Comparable {
    // ...
}

func == (lhs: SimpleDate, rhs: SimpleDate) -> Bool {
    // ...
}

func < (lhs: SimpleDate, rhs: SimpleDate) -> Bool {
    // ...
}
```

The remaining comparison operators `!=`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` are then provided
by generic library methods.